# Updating filter expression or filter value from one layer to another layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style, expression, filter, maptheme

From a `layer1` to which I apply a filter (`"field1"='value'`) in the provider feature filter dialog window, I would like to reuse this Expression, or just the attribute `'value'` in another `layer2` Filter dialog window.

So, if I change the value of the filter `'value'` in `layer1`, the value of the filter in `layer2` is also changed.

My aim is to avoid the copy/paste action of the `'value'` from one layer to another layer in the filter dialog window.

**Project description**:

1. In this case I have a project with only one layer (`layer1`) that I use for basic digitizing/capturing data.
2. I duplicate this layer rename it (`layer2`) and change the style.
3. I need the duplication of layers to create two different visualizations of the same data in the Layout.
4. In the Layout, I use two themes created with Manage Map Themes.

Here you can see the filter from `layer1`:

[image]

Here you can see the filter from `layer2`:

[image]

As you can see in the `layer2` filter, the value is a fake value. I only put the text of what I would like to update from `layer1`.

Comment: Sorry, question is confusing. Filter where? Attribute table? What does FIELD1="VALUE" represent? What is FIELD1? A fieldname? A string? And value is a fieldname? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry. I add more details answering your questions:

Filter on Query Builder
Expression is "FIELD1" = 'VALUE'. "FIELD1" means the name from the attribute table. "VALUE" means the value for which I filter the records
Format value is a String
I add a screenshot in my question

Comment: So you ask about provider filter (you access it from the layer properties, not from the attribute table, right?). I'm not sure but I don't think it's possible to access values from other layers. Maybe you should tell us a bit more about your use case and why you want to do that to see what other options you have.

Comment: Also be careful when using double quotes `"` (indicates a fieldname) and single quotes `'`, representing a text (string). Without any quotes, this also means a fieldname (`"name"` is the same as `name`, but different from `'name'`). This adds to the confusion. Correct syntax is like `"fieldname" = 'text_content_of_the_field'`

Comment: Ok. I have edit my text with the correct syntax to clarify the question

Comment: Babel, I add in my question a description of my project. I tell more about my case and why you would like to achieve the goal. I hope this can help us with alternative options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned, you want the second layer to be a copy of the first one, with another style, but the same Provider Feature Filter. I don't think you can access fields from another layer there, but there are better options for what you want to achieve: use [Rule-based styles](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#rule-based-rendering).

Set the provider feature filter on your layer, then set its style to Rule-Based. You can now create two or more completely different styles for the same layer.

You can now either manually check the boxes to show/hide the different styles or use [Map Themes](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#map-themes): activate the style you want, click the eye icon in the layer panel > `Add Theme...`. Activate another style and repeat. Now you can switch between styles by activating the themes - also in print layouts.

*A layer with a feature filter and two styles (red and blue). I defined three map themes: only red points, only blue points and both points:*

[image]