Filtered Features Appear When Exporting From QGIS Layout Manager
I'm using QGIS 3.34.11.In Layout Manager there are multiple maps on 1 layout. For some of these maps I want to filter out some features. I therefore lock the maps with the filtered features so that they aren't removed when I apply the filter in QGIS. This works on the layout view, so I have multiple maps from the canvas which have filtered polygon features for each map in the layout.
However, when I come to export the map the filtered layers reappear in Layout Manager and on the exported image. These are specific features that I want to remove in some maps so can't just deselect in the symbology. The only solution I thought of is to create multiple duplicate layers and turn them on and off when I lock the maps in layout manager

I think this answer could do what you want : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/469524/updating-filter-expression-or-filter-value-from-one-layer-to-another-layer-in-qg (as a side note I suggest that you use theme (https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#configuring-map-themes) rather than lock layer as this allow for easier modification on individual map)

Thanks J.R you are correct.

I copied the layers I was using in layout manager into groups to reflect the different combinations required in my small multiple map.
I then added filter to these copied layers to reflect the combination required for each small map and added a theme (not forgetting to turn all other groups off when doing this).
I then checked the 'Follow map theme' option in the main properties of each small map in layout manager.
When exporting the final small multiple map, each of the maps maintained the filtered features as required.
